# How to remove carriage return in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, replace, carriage-return, data-cleaning

I am having a dataframe that contains columns named id, country_name, location and total_deaths. While doing data cleaning process, I came across a value in a row that has `'\r'` attached. Once I complete cleaning process, I store the resulting dataframe in destination.csv file. Since the above particular row has `\r` attached, it always creates a new row.

```
id                               29
location            Uttar Pradesh\r
country_name                  India
total_deaths                     20
```

I want to remove `\r`. I tried `df.replace({'\r': ''}, regex=True)`. It isn't working for me.

Is there any other solution. Can somebody help?

#### Edit:

In the above process, I am iterating over df to see if `\r` is present. If present, then need to replace. Here `row.replace()` or `row.str.strip()` doesn't seem to be working or I could be doing it in a wrong way.

I don't want specify the column name or row number while using `replace()`. Because I can't be certain that only 'location' column will be having `\r`. Please find the code below.

```
count = 0
for row_index, row in df.iterrows():
    if re.search(r"\\r", str(row)):
        print type(row)               #Return type is pandas.Series
        row.replace({r'\\r': ''} , regex=True)
        print row
        count += 1
```

Comment: And `df.replace({r'\\r': ''}, regex=True)` does not work too? Why use `iterrows()`? I think it is not neccesary, because iterating is very slow.

Comment: I have no other way to iterate over df. `df.replace({r'\\r': ''}, regex=True)` isn't working

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Another solution is use [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df['29'] = df['29'].str.strip(r'\\r')
print df
             id             29
0      location  Uttar Pradesh
1  country_name          India
2  total_deaths             20
```

If you want use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), add `r` and one `\`:

```
print df.replace({r'\\r': ''}, regex=True)
             id             29
0      location  Uttar Pradesh
1  country_name          India
2  total_deaths             20
```

In `replace` you can define column for replacing like:

```
print df
               id               29
0        location  Uttar Pradesh\r
1    country_name            India
2  total_deaths\r               20

print df.replace({'29': {r'\\r': ''}}, regex=True)
               id             29
0        location  Uttar Pradesh
1    country_name          India
2  total_deaths\r             20

print df.replace({r'\\r': ''}, regex=True)
             id             29
0      location  Uttar Pradesh
1  country_name          India
2  total_deaths             20
```

EDIT by comment:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data_source_test.csv')
print df
   id country_name           location  total_deaths
0   1        India          New Delhi           354
1   2        India         Tamil Nadu            48
2   3        India          Karnataka             0
3   4        India      Andra Pradesh            32
4   5        India              Assam           679
5   6        India             Kerala           128
6   7        India             Punjab             0
7   8        India      Mumbai, Thane             1
8   9        India  Uttar Pradesh\r\n            20
9  10        India             Orissa            69

print df.replace({r'\r\n': ''}, regex=True)
   id country_name       location  total_deaths
0   1        India      New Delhi           354
1   2        India     Tamil Nadu            48
2   3        India      Karnataka             0
3   4        India  Andra Pradesh            32
4   5        India          Assam           679
5   6        India         Kerala           128
6   7        India         Punjab             0
7   8        India  Mumbai, Thane             1
8   9        India  Uttar Pradesh            20
9  10        India         Orissa            69
```

If need replace only in column `location`:

```
df['location'] = df.location.str.replace(r'\r\n', '')
print df
   id country_name       location  total_deaths
0   1        India      New Delhi           354
1   2        India     Tamil Nadu            48
2   3        India      Karnataka             0
3   4        India  Andra Pradesh            32
4   5        India          Assam           679
5   6        India         Kerala           128
6   7        India         Punjab             0
7   8        India  Mumbai, Thane             1
8   9        India  Uttar Pradesh            20
9  10        India         Orissa            69
```

Comment: thanks! The above solutions doesn't seem to solve my problem Or I might be doing something wrong. In the above process, basically I'm iterating over a dataframe and, check if `\r` is present. If present, then I need to perform replace. I have edited my question again.

Comment: Thanks. I add comment under question.

Comment: Ok, if use this `DataFrame` - `df = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 'location', 1: 'country_name', 2: 'total_deaths'}, 
                   '29': {0: 'Uttar Pradesh\\r', 1: 'India', 2: '20'}})`, it works? And what return `print df['29'].tolist()` ?

Comment: The above `DataFrame` returns me the following result:  `['Uttar Pradesh\\r', 'India', '20']`. I have added my test file and data source to [link] (https://github.com/itsmesaranya/data-cleaning) . Can you please have a look?

Comment: Please check my solution.

Comment: Wow! :) It works. This is what I have been trying for hours. Thank you so much. Looks like I need to learn a lot!

Answer (score 3):

use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html), you need to escape the sequence so it treats it as a carriage return rather than the literal `\r`:

```
In [15]:
df['29'] = df['29'].str.replace(r'\\r','')
df

Out[15]:
             id             29
0      location  Uttar Pradesh
1  country_name          India
2  total_deaths             20
```

Answer (score 3):

The below code removes \n tab spaces, \n new line and \r carriage return and is great for condensing datum into one row. The answer was taken from https://gist.github.com/smram/d6ded3c9028272360eb65bcab564a18a

```
df.replace(to_replace=[r"\\t|\\n|\\r", "\t|\n|\r"], value=["",""], regex=True, inplace=<INPLACE>)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make df equal to the df.replace code line and then print df.

```
df=df.replace({'\r': ''}, regex=True) 
print(df)
```

Comment: That answer already exists, word for word. I suggest you delete it to avoid cluttering the answer space with answers that already exist. Out of respect for future readers and the user who already posted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow, the accepted answer did not work for me. Ultimately, I found the solution by doing it like followed

```
df["29"] = df["29"].replace(r'\r', '', regex=True)
```

The difference is that I use `\r` instead of `\\r`.