# Issue with removing \n from pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-cleaning

I am trying to get rid of all \n from a whole pandas dataframe. I know there already are answers on this on stack overflow but for some reasons I cant get the desired output. I have the following dataframe:

```
  title     text    date    authors
0   [ECB completes foreign reserves investment in ...   [\nThe European Central Bank (ECB) completed an ...     [13 June 2017]  ECB
1   [Measures to improve the efficiency of the ope...   [\nThe Governing Council of the ECB has decided ...     [\n 23 January 2003 \n ]    ECB
2   []  []  []  ECB
3   [ECB publishes the results of the Euro Money M...   [Today the European Central Bank (ECB) is publ...   [\n 28 September 2012 \n ]  ECB
4   []  []  []  ECB
```

This is my desired output:

```
title   text    date    authors
0   [ECB completes foreign reserves investment in...    [The European Central Bank (ECB) completed an ...   [13 June 2017]  ECB
1   [Measures to improve the efficiency of the ope...   [The Governing Council of the ECB has decided ...   [23 January 2003]   ECB
2   []  []  []  ECB
3   [ECB publishes the results of the Euro Money M...   [Today the European Central Bank (ECB) is publ...   [28 September 2012]     ECB
4   []  []  []  ECB
```

These are all codes I tried:

1. based on [this stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37160929/how-to-remove-carriage-return-in-a-dataframe) post I tried:

   ```
   mydf=df.replace({r'\\n': ''}, regex=True)

   mydf=df['date'].str.strip(r'\\n') #this turns every obs into NaN 

   mydf=df.replace(to_replace=[r"\\n", "\n"], value=["",""], regex=True, inplace =True) #this gets rid of all data in dataframe for some reason
   ```

neither of which has worked

2. based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44227748/removing-newlines-from-messy-strings-in-pandas-dataframe-cells) I tried (note I am skipping answers which were already tried previously):

   `mydf=df.replace(r'\s', '', regex = True, inplace = True) #this deleted all data`
3. based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55510574/how-to-remove-newline-in-pandas-dataframe-columns) I tried:

   `mydf=df.replace('\\n',' ')`
4. based on comments for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52254186/remove-n-in-text-in-pandas-python) I tried:

   `mydf=df['date'].replace(r'\s+|\\n', ' ', regex=True, inplace=True)`
   and

   `mydf=df.replace(r'\s+|\\n', ' ', regex=True, inplace=True)`
5. based on answers in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46522652/replacing-newlines-with-spaces-for-str-columns-through-pandas-dataframe) I tried:

   `mydf= df.replace({r'\s+$': '', r'^\s+': ''}, regex=True).replace(r'\n',  ' ', regex=True)`

   `mydf=df.replace({ r'\A\s+|\s+\Z': '', '\n' : ' '}, regex=True, inplace=True) # this again deleted whole df`

I dont understand why the answers found there are not working in my case since they were accepted and most of those questions seem to be very similar to mine.

Comment: can you provide a sample df that we can copy into our browsers?

Comment: @Datanovice Sure, should I export the df and upload it somewhere or is there code in python that can give me output that I can copy paste here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
df['date']=df['date'].str[0].str.replace(r"\n", "")
```

That is under the assumption, that each cell in `date` column is a list with only 1 element. It will also flatten it - so you will get string from that single element.

IF however `date` can contain more than one element, and you want to merge them all into single string after you get rid of all `\n` - try

```py
df['date']=df['date'].str.join('').str.replace(r"\n", "")
```

Otherwise, if you wish to keep it in the list format, just stripping all elements of `\n` try (`&&` being interim separator):

```py
df['date']=df['date'].str.join(r'&&').str.replace(r"\n", "").str.split(r'&&')
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! By the way I am curios about .str[0], usually when you examine lists list[0] gives you the first entry in the list, does str[0] in data frame refers to the whole column? I am asking because I am bit puzzled about it from the first look I would think that would correct only the first date not all of them

Comment: Glad to hear that :) ```.str[0]``` is the way to get the first item of the list, but as a vectorized function i.e. if you have ```pandas.Series``` with each row having an iterable in it, it will return first element for each row's iterable.

Comment: oh got it, I though you always need some kind of for loop for that, good to know. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {'col1': [['\n a b c'], ['\n x y z']], 'col2': [[1.5000], ['\n x y z']]}
df20 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

print(df20)

def remove_spec_char(string_list=list):
    y = []
    for string_x in string_list:
        if type(string_x) == str:
            y.append(string_x.replace('\n', ''))
        else:
            y.append(string_x)
    return y



for c in df20.columns:

    df20[c] = df20[c].apply(remove_spec_char)

print(df20)
```

Comment: I tried this: `def remove_spec_char(string_x=str):
    return string_x.replace('\n', '')

for c in df.columns:

    df[c] = df[c].apply(remove_spec_char)

print(df)` but I get the following error: 
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: please check the above code, edited to process lists

Comment: I tried this but now it thinks the object is a float. I get an error for the `df[c] = df[c].apply(remove_spec_char)` TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable. I dont get whats happening because all columns in dataframe contain texts so they should be strings

Comment: @BhosaleShirkant the code runs without error but it does not produce desired output. The Grzegorz Skibinski answer worked for me so I dont need help anymore but I give you +1 because I appreciate all the effort you put into your answer